# problem of dissecting a 1 x k rectangle into similar but incongruent polygons

Tags: geometry, polygons

I have this problem from USAMO 2004:

"For what values of $k > 0$ is it possible to dissect a $1 \times k$ rectangle into two similar, but incongruent, polygons?"

I feel that all values of k will satisfy, since for any rectangle with a given k, I draw a line which intersects the opposite sides of the rectangle at unequal distances from the opposite vertices and I get 2 polygons which are similar but incongruent. However, I have a few doubts, this is USAMO so I personally don't think such a solution would be deemed correct, moreover the answer says that k should not be equal to one

Why is that so? And any mistakes with my solution?

Comment: In geometry, 'similar' means 'exactly the same shape except a different size'.  So angles have to match, and ratios of sides have to match.

Comment: oh yeah angles as well as ratios must match, thanks for helping me realise it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there might be a fractal solution, with two shapes bounded by this sequence of horizontal and vertical lines:

$$(0,0),(1,0),(1,x),(1+x^2,x),(1+x^2,x+x^3),(1+x^2+x^4,x+x^3),...$$
end at the far corner

$$\left(\frac1{1-x^2},\frac x{1-x^2}\right)$$

Comment: That is exactly what he has done on this site https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=2004_USAMO_Problems/Problem_3 Can you help me prove that I can do it for any k? Specificaly, I didn't understand what has the author done in the last step in the above link

Comment: What Empy2 has done here is construct a fractal solution, which is not a valid solution since a polygon has a finite number of sides and a fractal does not. The page you link to seems to show that you can construct a similar solution but with a finite number of steps $n$, and furthermore that it works for any $k>1$. The closer you get to $k=1$ the larger $n$ needs to be, and that leaves only $k=1$ unsolvable.

Answer (score 0):

Other comments have answered the question you asked (namely, is your solution correct?). I'm going to push on and help you see where the really interesting part of this problem lies (a part that I will not solve because I don't know how to do it!).

Despite your solution being not quite right, it's *almost* right.

It's still possible to split the strip into exactly two rectangles (except for particular values of $k$): you make one of them *almost* $1 \times k$, and the other be $1$ unit tall and about $1/k$ wide. More precisely, you want to get this picture:

```
|----------------------|-|
|                      | |
|                      | |
|----------------------|-|
```

where the first rectangle is $1 \times a$, and the other is $1 \times b$, and

1. $a + b = k$
2. $a/1$ is the same as $1/b$, so that they are similar.

Solving gives $ab = 1$, so $a + \frac{1}{a} = k$, hence
$$
a^2 -ka + 1 = 0
$$
and
$$
a = \frac{k \pm \sqrt{k^2 - 4}}{2}
$$
Because only values of $a$ less than $k$ make sense, only one of these two roots is a good choice.

There are two clear problems remaining:

1. If $k = 2$, the two rectangles are both $1 \times 2$, and hence are similar *and* congruent, adn you need a different solution (if there is one).
2. For $k < 2$, this approach, as written, doesn't get you an answer. But if you rotate the diagram above by 90 degrees, you can still get something by essentially the same method. The $1 \times k$ rectangle becomes $k \times 1$, which you can scale down to $1 \times 1/k$, for which the previous method works when $1/k > 2$, i.e., when $k < \frac{1}{2}$. (Thanks to @JaapScherphuis for pointing this out).

So the whole thing boils down to the $1/2 \le k \le 2$ question (for which I don't see an obvious answer in either direction, personally). As Jaap observes, rotation lets us assume $k > 1$, so really the unanswered range is $1 \le k \le 2$.

Comment: Rotating by 90 degrees changes the problem from a $1\times k$ rectangle to a $k\times 1$ rectangle, or equivalently a $1\times 1/k$ rectangle. You've solved $k>2$, and $k<1/2$. So there is not just $k=2$ left, but the whole interval $1/2 \le k \le 2$. (Or just $[1,2]$ since we can rotate to make $k\ge1$.)

Comment: Thanks @JaapScherphuis --- good point. I'll edit